The Medians of Lipschitz Functions on $(X,d,\mu)$ (Existence and Uniqueness)

Let $\varphi:(X,d,\mu)\to \Bbb R$ be a Lipschitz function, where $\mu$ is a probability measure on the metric space $(X,d)$. The median $m_\varphi$ of $\varphi$ is defined as the real number such that
$$\mu\left(\{x\in X: \varphi(x) \geqslant  m_\varphi\}\right) \ge \frac{1}{2}, \tag{1}$$
and
$$\mu\left(\{x\in X: \varphi(x) \leqslant  m_\varphi\}\right) \ge \frac{1}{2}. \tag{2}$$
Show that the median $m_\varphi$ exists, and is unique.

Say $\varphi$ is $L$-Lipschitz, i.e.,
$$|\varphi(x) - \varphi(y)| \le L\, d(x,y),$$ for all $x,y\in X$. I'll try the proof of uniqueness first. Suppose $m_\varphi$ and $m_\varphi'$ are both medians of $\varphi$, i.e., they satisfy inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$. WLOG, assume $m_\varphi < m_\varphi'$. Then,
$$\mu(\{x\in X: \varphi(x) \geqslant m_\varphi\}) = \mu(\{x\in X: \varphi(x) \geqslant m_\varphi'\}) + \mu(\{x\in X: m_\varphi' > \varphi(x) \geqslant m_\varphi\}), \tag{3}$$
and
$$\mu(\{x\in X: \varphi(x) \leqslant m_\varphi'\}) = \mu(\{x\in X: \varphi(x) \leqslant m_\varphi\}) + \mu(\{x\in X: m_\varphi' \geqslant \varphi(x) > m_\varphi\}). \tag{4}$$
The bounds from $(1)$ and $(2)$ do not yield much unless I am missing something. I am unsure how to get started for proof of existence. I haven't yet used the Lipschitzness of $\varphi$; which might be key to both the proofs. Thanks!

Under the generality of the question, uniqueness is not guaranteed. For instance, consider $X = [-1,1]$ with its usual distance, $\varphi(x) = x$ and $\mu = (1/2)\delta_{-1/2} + (1/2)\delta_{1/2}$ (where $\delta_x$ is the probability measure supported at the point $x$); then any $m \in (-1/2, 1/2)$ is a median.

Thanks @JordanPayette. My reference is Pg. 3 of Barvinok's notes - could you perhaps decipher the right amount of generality in which the statement holds? Going forward, the results in this area are not limited to the sphere $S^{n-1}$, but generalize to metric probability spaces $(X,d,\mu)$; hence my question. Thanks again!

Short answer: Existence and uniqueness of a median (of a continuous function $\varphi : X \to \mathbb{R}$) follow under the additional assumptions (i) $\mathrm{supp}(\mu) = X$, (ii) $X$ is connected and (iii) $\mu$ is tight.
Concerning Uniqueness: Uniqueness of the median (in the sense of equations (1) and (2) from the question) is not guaranteed under the generality of the question. I gave the counter-example of $X = [-1,1]$ with its usual metric, $\varphi(x) = x$ and $\mu = (1/2)(\delta_{-1/2} + \delta_{1/2})$ (where $\delta_x$ denotes the probability measure supported at point $x$); then any $m \in [-1/2,1/2]$ is a median. Another counter-example is $X = \{0,1\}$ with the induced metric from $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\mu = (1/2)(\delta_0 + \delta_1)$ and $\varphi(x) = x \in \mathbb{R}$ (which is $1$-Lipschitz); then any $m \in [0,1]$ is a median.
To achieve uniqueness, it suffices to add two conditions: (i) the support of $\mu$ be the whole of $X$ (equivalently, that $\mu(U) > 0$ for all nonempty open set $U \subset X$), and (ii) $X$ is connected.
Indeed, under those assumptions, consider a continuous function $\varphi : X \to \mathbb{R}$. Wlog, we assume (*) $\varphi$ is not a constant.
Let $m < m' \in \mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$. By continuity, $U := \varphi^{-1}((m, m'))$ is open. $U$ is nonempty, for otherwise we would have $X = \varphi^{-1}((-\infty, m]) \sqcup \varphi^{-1}([m', + \infty))$, i.e., $X$ would be a disjoint union of two closed sets, contradicting (ii). From (i), we thus have $\mu(U) > 0$.
Now assume that both $m$ and $m'$ are medians. Then
\begin{align}
1  = \mu(X) &= \mu(\{ x : \varphi(x) \le m \}) + \mu(\{ x : \varphi(x) > m \}) \\
&= \mu(\{ x : \varphi(x) \le m \})  + \mu(\{ x : \varphi(x) \ge m' \}) + \mu(U) \\
&\ge (1/2) + (1/2) + \mu(U) ,
\end{align}
whence $0 \ge \mu(U)$. This absurd conclusion proves the uniqueness of the median.
Concerning Existence: We still assume (i), (ii) and wlog (*).
To achieve existence of the median, it suffices to add the condition: (iii) the measure $\mu$ is tight (i.e. inner regular). (This is a relatively weak assumption in practice: If $(X, d)$ is a Polish space (i.e. complete and separable), then $\mu$ is tight by a version of Prokhorov's theorem.)
To fix ideas, let's assume wlog that (**) $\varphi : X \to (0,1)$. Indeed, given any $\varphi : X \to \mathbb{R}$, consider any (Lipschitz) homeomorphism $f : \mathbb{R} \to (0,1)$ (e.g., $f(y) = e^y/(1+e^y)$) and $\varphi' = f \circ \varphi$. Assuming we know the existence of a median $m_{\varphi'}$ for $\varphi'$, then $m := f^{-1}(m_{\varphi'})$ is a median for $\varphi$.
Consider the cumulative probability distribution $F(y) = \mu(\{x : \varphi(x) \le y\})$ and consider the set $S := \{y \in \mathbb{R}\, : \, F(y) \ge 1/2\}$.
By (**), $S \subset [0, \infty)$. $S$ is nonempty, as $1 \in S$. $F$ is non-decreasing (in fact, increasing by (i), (ii) and (*)), so $y \in S$ implies $y' \in S$ for all $y' \ge y$. Let $m := \mathrm{inf} \, S$, which is a number in $(0,1]$.
Claim: $m$ is a median of $\varphi$.
Note that $S$ is either of the form (a) $[m, +\infty)$ or (b) $(m, + \infty)$.
Under Option (a), we have $F(m) \ge 1/2$ (so $m$ satisfies condition (2) for a median) and $F(y) < 1/2$ for all $y < m$. Assume $m$ is not a median, i.e. $\mu(\{x : \varphi(x) \ge m\}) < 1/2$, so that $F(m) \ge \mu(\{x : \varphi(x) < m\}) > 1/2$. By (iii), there exists a compact set $K \subset \{x : \varphi(x) < m\}$ such that $\mu(K) > 1/2$. Since $\varphi$ is continuous on $K$, it attains a maximum $y$ on $K$ (which is necessarily strictly less than $m$). Thus we have $K \subset \{x : \varphi(x) \le y\}$. Hence $1/2 < F(y) < 1/2$, which is absurd. Hence $m$ is a median.
Option (b) is impossible. Indeed, assuming (b), we have $F(m) < 1/2$ (so $m$ fails condition (2) for a median) and $F(y) \ge 1/2$ for all $y > m$. In fact, $F(y) > 1/2$ for all such $y$: if we had $F(y) = 1/2$ for some $y > m$, then since $F$ is strictly increasing, we would have $F(y') < F(y) = 1/2$ for all $y' < y$, contradicting the definition of $m$. Hence $\mu(\{ x : \varphi(x) > y \}) < 1/2$ when $y > m$. The open set $U_m := \{ x : \varphi(x) > m\}$ satisfies $\mu(U_m) = 1 - F(m) > 1/2$. By (iii), there exists a compact $K \subset U_m$ such that $\mu(K) > 1/2$. Since $\varphi$ is continuous on $K$, it attains its minimum $y'$ on $K$, where $y' > m$.  Hence for any $y' > y>m$ we have $K \subset \{ x : \varphi(x) > y \}$; applying $\mu$ on both sides, we get $1/2 < 1/2$, which is absurd. Hence Option (b) does not hold.

Thank you, that's a very nice answer!
